# MSSQL Function giving mssql_query(): Query Failed

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have the following PHP snippet which is retrieving records:

```
    $thecall = "EXEC Web.spSearch @Keyword = \"$search\", @Publication = $publication";

    $search_results = mssql_query( $thecall); 
    if( $search_results === false ) { die( print_r( mssql_get_last_message(), true)); }

    $search_total = mssql_query( $thecall); 
    if( $search_total === false ) { die( print_r( mssql_get_last_message(), true)); }

    do {
        $counter=0;
        while ($obj=mssql_fetch_object($search_total)) 
        {
            $total++;
        }
    } while (mssql_next_result($search_total));
```

When run it gives:

```
Error : mssql_query(): Query failed
```

When I commented the line:

```
$search_total = mssql_query( $thecall);
```

The error was not being presented anymore, but instead the following was coming up: "Error : mssql_fetch_object() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given" - as expected since $search_total was not being defined anymore.

Could someone help point out the issue with this snippet please?

Comment: Is switching to http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlsrv.php an option?

Comment: I'm working on a Linux machine. The sqlsrv function requires a Windows environment. So not really an option :/